# How to set video frame width and video frame height in OMX.broadcom.video_decode component?

Tags: c, multimedia, openmax

I was trying a video player pipeline using openmax, which accepts raw h264 streams decodes it and pass it to render. While configuring the ports, I want to set the frame width and frame height to 1280 * 720. But I was getting bad parameter error while setting the parameters. How to set the frame width and frame height for a port in an openmax component, As i m a newbie to these framework, my knowledge is limited. Is there any other feilds I should set before setting the width and height ?

This is how i tried to set the parameter

```
    memset(&portdef,0,sizeof(OMX_PARAM_PORTDEFINITIONTYPE));
    portdef.nSize = sizeof(OMX_PARAM_PORTDEFINITIONTYPE);
    portdef.nVersion.nVersion = OMX_VERSION;
    portdef.nPortIndex = 131; 


    portdef.format.video.nFrameWidth = 1280;
    portdef.format.video.nFrameHeight = 720; 

    portdef.nBufferSize = portdef.format.video.nFrameWidth * portdef.format.video.nFrameHeight * 3 / 2;

    /* set the video decode properties */
    if((error = OMX_SetParameter(video_decode,OMX_IndexParamPortDefinition,&portdef)) != OMX_ErrorNone)
        printf("set parameter error for decoder %x\n",error);
```

And I was getting the error as

```
set parameter error for decoder 80001005
```

and that is the bad parameter error. Why is it comming ?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is `OMX_ErrorBadParameter`, it might be caused by setting `nCountActuals` to zero.

If your board is something old it is worthy to check media_profiles.xml if 1280x720 is supported by the component.

Check if hard coded `nPortIndex` is set to correct value (it should return 0x8000101B `OMX_ErrorBadIndex` in case of an error, but I saw implementation which returned `OMX_ErrorBadParameter` instead).

Is 131 output port? If so, you should set also colour format, now it would be set to `OMX_COLOR_FormatUnused`.